# why is my nested if in for loop not working?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, zero

I have a dataframe on bat activity with variables

"plot_no"     "date"        "rec_hour"    "guild"       "sunrise"     "sunriseEnd"  "sunsetStart" "sunset"    "count"       "id"

where ID is a character combination of plot_no, date, rec_hour and guild.

At the moment, if there were no observations for a certain plot_no, date, time and guild, there is no line in the dataframe. I would like to have all relevant combinations of those variables and have a count of zero when there was no observation.

In order to do that, I made a new dataframe with all combinations and all zeros for count. Now I want to add the right count into the zero dataframe using this code:

```
for (nr in dim(Bat_Data_zeros_)[1]) {
  if (dim(Bat_Data_count[Bat_Data_zeros_$id[nr] == Bat_Data_count$id,])[1]>0) {
    Bat_Data_zeros_$count[nr] <- Bat_Data_count$count[Bat_Data_zeros_$id[nr] == Bat_Data_count$id]
  }
}
```

but only one value (not even the first one) gets replaced. I checked every part of the code separately to see if it gave the output I was expecting and it all seemed right. I also tried using str_detect (was my first attempt) on the IDs, but the str_detect function for some reason gives back way more matches than there actually are.

Comment: without sample data it's really difficult to give you a solution. One common suspect is spelling, are you sure your IDs are spelled exactly the same way? (leading / trailing spaces can often cause such issues)

Comment: Yes, they're spelled the same way, I checked manually by searching some examples in the different dataframes and they always line up. Like I said every separate part of the code seems to work on it's own, but not within the loop.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel when `tidyr::complete` will do this for you?

Comment: Obviously bc I didn't know about the function :) thanks for helping, figured it out